# Pipelining of data.frame in R

Tags: r

What use when I have a data.frame like this:

```
data(iris)
head(iris)
```

and I want to get a vector which is Petal.Width * 2 if Species=="Setosa" If not I want to get a Petal.Width * 1 and length of result vector must be == nrow(iris).

Use sapply? vcast? I donno.

```
sapply(iris,function(iris){
  if (iris$Species=="setosa")
    {iris$Petal.Width*2}else{
      iris$Petal.Width*1}})
```

Comment: you can use `ifelse`

Comment: `ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", iris$Petal.Width * 2, iris$Petal.Width)`

Comment: use `if_else` from `dplyr` i.e. `iris %>% mutate(new = if_else(Species == "setosa", Petal.Width * 2, Petal.Width))`

Comment: ifelse didnt repair the problem

Comment: What is %>% ??? I cant google it...

Comment: @UekonometriaUekonometria are you getting any error? Can you share the expected output? because it is working for me.

Comment: @Ronak Shah , I got: Error in iris$Species : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. I used "transform" except "sapply" and now its ok.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but.... would `iris$Petal.Width*c(2, 1, 1)[iris$Species]` be a valid answer?